# PHP Site works in Mobile but in Desktop it says mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002)

Tags: php, codeigniter, mobile, browser, desktop

I Hope you can help me.

When I access my website in a desktop browser it gives me a connection error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity:    Warning
Message:     mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
Filename:    mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 203
```

If I access my website in a mobile browser, it doesn't show the error and I can access the site ok.

If I use a desktop browser like Chrome, open Developer Tools (F12) and select a Mobile User Agents it also works.

I don't know where to look for a solution. Could you please give me some troubleshooting tips?

Im using PHP 7.4 / Codeignter 3.1.1

Thanks !

EDIT: I've translated the error message to english

Comment: How does the code differ for mobile? Can you translate `No existe el fichero o el directorio` sounds like a directory doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes! Sorry. No such file or directory. The code doesn't has any difference. I think it's a cloudfare issue but i don't know how to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this but doing the following:

- I restore in cpanel my files to a backup of 5 days earlier.
- In Cloudfare, I did a purge all cache.

I don't know what happen, I believe it's related to cache and htaccess but i didn't know how to troubleshoot it.

I post my answer so if anyone in the future see this know what I did.